# Extension and higher-order functions referencing

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

I get an overall idea of what is each of these, I wrote piece of code however that I don't quite understand why it works.
The thing is `callExtensionOnString` expects extension function as its parameter, however it doesn't complain if reference to `printString` is passed.
Is `String.() -> Unit` just another name for `(String) -> Unit` type or is it Kotlin compiler that takes some kind of shortcut to fit higher order in extension function?

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    callExtensionOnString(::printString)
}

fun callExtensionOnString(extensionFun: String.() -> Unit) {
    "testString".extensionFun()
}

fun printString(str: String) {
    println(str)
}
```

Then there is second thing that seems unclear to me. `printString` reference is passed once to `callExtensionOnString` and then again to `run` function which basically requires `String.() -> Unit` extension function. Is there difference between these two so that second time `::` prefix is omitted?

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runFunctionOnString(::printString)
}

fun runFunctionOnString(higherOrderFun: (String) -> Unit) {
    "testString".run(higherOrderFun)
}

fun printString(str: String) {
    println(str)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning your first question, these 2 are equivalent:

```
"testString".extensionFun()
extensionFun("testString")
```

That's why passing `printString` method doesn't cause a compilation error.

Concerning the second question, the difference is that `highOrderFun` is already a reference to a function, while `printString` is not a function reference (but you can obtain it with the `::` operator)